# Cannot input in Edittext in avd using hardware keyboard

Tags: android

I cannot type text in android emulator using hardware keyboard. I've also added "keyboard support" on my emulator but still I cannot input text.

Please help me how to enable the hardware keyboard. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Do make sure that you have set the Keyboard support value to yes. The default value is no.

Comment: I still cannot type after setting the keyboard support value to yes.

Answer (score 1):

1.Go to Android SDK Manager 
2.From Tools click on Manage AVDs
2.Select the AVD and click on Edit
3.In the Hardware section, click on New
4.Select the Property 'Keyboard Support' and press OK
5.Click on the value column of 'keyboard Support' and change it to 'yes'.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to Android SDK Manager.
2. From Tools click on Manage AVDs.
3. Select the AVD and click on Edit.
4. In the Hardware section, click on New.
5. Select the Property 'Keyboard Support' and press OK.
6. Click on the value column of 'keyboard Support' and change it to 'yes'.
7. Restart your AVD.